# An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: trace, wcf-web-api

I am trying to consume WCF web service and get following error. Its a third party service so dont have much control over it.

I have tried making tracing work but nothing seems to work. Cant get tracing work

Error i get is

`` An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code ``

`Additional information: Shared key was empty`

Inner exception comes as Null and Reason is Shared Key is empty.

Has anyone came across this problem while consuming WCF web service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it a third party webservice, they didn't provide me with the code which adds 'Shared Key' variable as its individual for each client.

Asked the client and they provided the code with my shared key and that fixed the problem.